Webpack dev server display doesn't source map my error
When I run my app on webpack server (webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js) I am testing the error source mapping. In a file print.js I have a bug. When I open the website from the server it displays a bug

I need it to show me the exact file from the bug, not the bundle
My webpack.common.js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: "./src/index.js",
    print: "./src/print.js",
  },
  devtool: "source-map",

  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    clean: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Development",
    }),
  ],
};


My webpack dev file
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    static: "./dist",
    client: {
      overlay: true,
    },
  },
});


I tried clearing cache, changing mapping methods but still nothing works. It stills shows me bundle not the exact file

The unhandled runtime errors shown in the overlay can't show the source map line. See Error Overlay Shows Un-Source-Mapped Lines issue.
However, the errors in the browser console can show the source map line. But you need to enable below setting of the devtools:
Settings -> Preferences -> Sources -> JavaScript source maps
Before enabling this setting, the error in the console will show the compiled code line:
Uncaught ReferenceError: cosnole is not defined
   at HTMLButtonElement.printMe (index.bundle.js:3299:3)
printMe @ index.bundle.js:3299

After enabling this setting, reload the page. Click the button, it will show the source map line.
Uncaught ReferenceError: cosnole is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.printMe (print.js:2:1)
printMe @ print.js:2

When you click the print.js:2:1, you will be navigated to the file from the source map.


As per the answer from Lin Du this is not natively possible in webpack ATM, but there is a package error-overlay-webpack-plugin that can do what you are looking for with a couple of quirks to make it work.
Also disable the native webpack overlay or you'll have 2 overlays to shut down:
 devServer: {
        client: {
            overlay: false,
        }
    }

" Click to open error line in editor" does not seem to work on my setup, but it's still a great alternative to the native overlay.
